# Laravel 9 - Testing Expected response status code [201] but received 403

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-9

I use "WithoutMiddleware" to through Passport + Spatie permission Middleware but it not working.

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;

class BlueprintTest extends TestCase
{
use WithoutMiddleware; // use this trait

    public function test_store_success()
    {
        $this->withoutMiddleware();
        $response = $this
            ->withHeaders(['Accept' => 'application/json'])
            ->json('POST', '/api/v1/blueprints',$this->row_data);
    
        $response->assertStatus(201);
        $response->assertJson(['data' => $this->row_data]);
    
    }

}
```

There was 1 failure:

1. Tests\Feature\BlueprintTest::test_store_success
   Expected response status code [201] but received 403.
   Failed asserting that 201 is identical to 403.

my assert is status code "201"

Comment: is `/api/v1/blueprints` sit behind auth middleware?

Comment: yes i use middleware passport + spatie permission  
when i call api without Authorization i recieved 401 UNAUTHORIZED
and run unit testing receive 403 FORBIDDEN

Comment: i havent write laravel for a long while, but there was [an issue which says `withoutMiddleware()` wont work on globally registered middleware](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32384). the laravel passport uses a different way to mock a request, [see docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#testing).

Comment: Why would you not use the middleware in a feature test? That is wrong as you are not fully testing your feature... just create a user, and use `$this->actingAs($user)`...

Comment: But 403 is a forbidden probably meaning you don't have the permission needed?

Comment: yes i don't have permission  Now i can use `$this->actingAs($user)`  but it require select 1 user from Database Model .  Do you have any way to mocking passport token  without table "users"? I just ask for possibility, if not then I will select from database as usual.